# After() conflicting with Destroy() in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a problem using *after()* and *destroy()* methods. I created a meniu when I'm monitoring the ram status and processor status. When I'm calling first def it's okay but when I'm calling second def, exemple processor status the information inside the frame is showing for few milliseconds and then the information about ram status, and again over and over.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPZoj.gif

```
def ram():
root.after(1000,ram)
for widget in app.winfo_children():
    widget.destroy()
iram = psutil.virtual_memory()
total = iram.total / (1024*1024)
available = iram.available /(1024*1024)
percent = iram.percent
used = iram.used /(1024*1024)

inf = Label(app, text="Information about RAM status")
inf.grid(row=0,column=1, pady=10)

total_1 = Label(app, text="Total memory RAM")
total_1.grid(row=1,column=0)

total1 = Label(app, text=total,fg="blue")
total1.grid(row=1, column=1,pady=5)

available_1 = Label(app, text="Available memory RAM")
available_1.grid(row=2,column=0)

available1 = Label(app, text=available,fg="blue")
available1.grid(row=2, column=1,pady=5)

percent_1 = Label(app, text="Used memory RAM in %")
percent_1.grid(row=3,column=0)

percent1 = Label(app, text=percent,fg="red")
percent1.grid(row=3, column=1,pady=5)

used_1 = Label(app, text="Used memory RAM")
used_1.grid(row=4,column=0)

used1 = Label(app, text=used,fg="blue")
used1.grid(row=4, column=1,pady=5)

def help():
for widget in app.winfo_children():
    widget.destroy()
help_1=Label(app, text="This aplication was created with Python 3.5 \n")
help_1.grid(row=0,column=0)

root = Tk()
app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
root.title("S.M.A.R.T.")
root.geometry("500x300")
root.resizable(0,0)
menubar = Menu(root)

filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Battery Status", command=battery_status)
filemenu.add_command(label="Disk's Status", command=disk_status)
filemenu.add_command(label="Processor Status", command=processor)
filemenu.add_command(label="PC's Status", command=pc)
filemenu.add_command(label="RAM's Status", command=ram)
filemenu.add_command(label="Windows Status", command=windows)
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

filemenu.add_separator()

menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
helpmenu.add_command(label="Help", command=help)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)
helpmenu.add_separator()
root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

What I supposed to do for avoid this problem? Cause it recall those submenus and it's impossible to understand information in the frame.

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is unclear, but I think what you're asking is how to stop updating the old information when you request different information.

`after` returns an identifier, which you can pass to `after_cancel` in order to prevent the function from being called again. So, your menu commands simply need to cancel any pending job before scheduling a new job.

It would look something like this:

```
global after_id
after_id = None
...
def cancel_old_job():
    global after_id
    if after_id is not None:
        root.after_cancel(after_id)
        after_id = None
    ...
def ram():
    global after_id
    cancel_old_job()
    after_id = root.after(1000,ram)
    ...
def pc():
    global after_id
    cancel_old_job()
    after_id = root.after(1000,pc)
    ...
...
```